# Added Gradle dependencies can not be imported in Java classes

Tags: java, gradle, import, dependencies

I added the servlet api as a dependency in Gradle, but when I want to import it in my Java class, it does not work. Same thing with the Mockito Framework.

My gradle.build file Looks like this:

```
group 'Dontknownow'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.4-3'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'kotlin2js'
apply plugin: 'war'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
   jcenter()
}

dependencies {
   compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-js:$kotlin_version"
   testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
   testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
   testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.+'
   providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
}
```

This is how the error looks like in my IntelliJ:
[image: the name mockito is marked red in the import-statement]

Comment: It's not a mindless copy. This is the way how IntelliJ generates my build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

Okey I solved it by myself.

I think the "+" in my build.gradle was the problem 
Instead of using

```
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.+'
```

i entered an absolute version:

```
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.7.19'
```

and also there where alternative import-statements for Mockito on https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-web-applications/

```
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
```